# Just need a little help to finish up this script

Tags: javascript

Basically, I am trying to get the formula to put out to "all" but I have to remove the $ from the value first which is the first script's job. I just don't know how to combine the two.

```
<p id="a" class="hide"></p>

<p id="all" class="pricing-text-all-in"></p>

<script>
var Amount = '$13.22'; //monthly payment
var ReplacedAmount = Amount.replace(/\$/g,'');
document.getElementById("a").innerHTML =(ReplacedAmount);
</script>

<script>
var a = "a"; //monthly payment
var c = 5; //tax
var d = 15; //L&R
var e = 55; //total due at signing
var z = e - ( a + c + d );
document.getElementById("all").innerHTML = z;

</script>
```

Comment: What do you mean you "don't know how to combine the two"?  What have you tried to combine them?

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use the variable from the first script in the second one and make sure to convert it to a number (prepending it with `+` implicitly does this).

Also, you don't need two scripts here and you shouldn't use `.innerHTML` since your not reading or writing any HTML. Use `.textContent` instead.

Lastly, don't name a variable the same name as the `id` of an element on the page as this can cause issues since `id`s become globals.

```html
<p id="a" class="hide"></p>

<p id="all" class="pricing-text-all-in"></p>

<script>
  var amount = '$13.22'; //monthly payment
  var replacedAmount = amount.replace(/\$/g,'');
  document.getElementById("a").textContent = replacedAmount;

  var c = 5; //tax
  var d = 15; //L&R
  var e = 55; //total due at signing
  document.getElementById("all").textContent = e - (+replacedAmount + c + d );
</script>
```

Comment: Can you recommend anywhere to read more about your last point? ("Lastly, don't name a variable the same name as the id of an element on the page as this can cause issues since ids become globals.")

Comment: @Cat Not off the top of my head, but a [Google search on the topic](https://www.google.com/search?q=element+id+becomes+global&rlz=1C1GCEU_enUS839US839&oq=element+id+becomes+global&aqs=chrome..69i57j33i160l2.5311j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) brings up many relevant results. This is something that is an artifact left over from the earliest days of the BOM (browser object model). Any element that has an `id` becomes globally available within that page through its `id`, so if you create a variable with the same name as an `id`, you create a potential conflict.